# How can I convert a comma-separated string to an array?

Tags: javascript, string, csv, split

I have a comma-separated string that I want to convert into an array, so I can loop through it.

Is there anything built-in to do this?

For example, I have this string

```
var str = "January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December";
```

Now I want to split this by the comma, and then store it in an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I parse a CSV string with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript)

Comment: Regarding duplicate: this predates the referenced question by 18 months.  If anything, the other is not only a dupe but offers an extremely complicated solution for a very simple problem due to the regex requirement

Answer (score 1483, accepted):

```
const array = str.split(',');
```

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), mostly helpful for the possibly unexpected behavior of the `limit` parameter. (Hint: `"a,b,c".split(",", 2)` comes out to `["a", "b"]`, not `["a", "b,c"]`.)

Comment: While `split` will work fine if you are sure you have elements in `array`, if you're expecting data from a server / database you will run into trouble since `''.split(',')` has a `length === 1`
IE: `''.split(',') === ['']`

Comment: this is for comma separated but what if i want to separate with 'and' ',' '&' ?? how will you do it

Comment: What if there is more then one sting and some strings have no comma. How can i retirn one member arrays?

Comment: a way of solving empty string element when ''.split(',') === [''] is filtering string.split(',').filter(e => e !== '')

Comment: @VladGoran I am trying to split the values before using $in operator with mongo. It does not work. Could you help?

Answer (score 146):

Watch out if you are aiming at integers, like 1,2,3,4,5. If you intend to use the elements of your array as integers and not as strings after splitting the string, consider converting them into such.

```
var str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
var temp = new Array();
// This will return an array with strings "1", "2", etc.
temp = str.split(",");
```

Adding a loop like this,

```
for (a in temp ) {
    temp[a] = parseInt(temp[a], 10); // Explicitly include base as per Álvaro's comment
}
```

will return an array containing integers, and not strings.

Comment: Please note that parseInt() tries to guess the base unless you explicit set it, which can cause unexpected results when dealing with leading zeros (`"001,002,003..."`). Compare `parseInt('010')` with `parseInt('010', 10)`.

Comment: +1 This example is more clear, demonstrating that string is not a static object but in fact the variable that is the string.

Comment: The `map` function can be used to do the integer parsing in one line: `str.split(',').map(parseInt)`

Comment: My first number always still has a quote character in front.
```""25342","56743","457863""```
becomes
```"25342,56743,457863"```
This makes parseInt unable to number-ise the first number
```"25342```
giving me NaN. I strip them now first before parseInting (in a for loop, not for..in; does that matter?). Would be nice to avoid that extra line if possible.

Comment: Seems like you are forcing a set of strings "25342", "56743", "457863" to wrap into another set of "" which gives you a string of strings. Mind looking at this extra-wrapping first?

Comment: This is not the most efficient solution. According to my experiments under Chrome 49. JSON.parse('[' + str + ']') is 40% faster than this solution.

Comment: @Yao your solution won't work `JSON.parse('['1,2,3,4,5']');` is not going to magically separate 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález using Number('010') doesn't have the problem you describe. Also other issue can be handled by upgrading your use of `split`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69966162/8910547

Comment: @Inigo This was written 11 years ago. Things have changed. ECMAScript 5 actually disallows interpreting strings with leading zero as octal. ([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#octal_interpretations_with_no_radix)).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, sure, but it is important to update/clarify because your comment has 47 upvotes. People see that, not the date.

Answer (score 38):

Hmm, split is dangerous IMHO as a string can always contain a comma. Observe the following:

```
var myArr = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,','";
result = myArr.split(',');
```

So how would you interpret that? And what do you *want* the result to be? An array with:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', '\'', '\''] or
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', ',']
```

Even if you escape the comma, you'd have a problem.

I quickly fiddled this together:

```
(function($) {
    $.extend({
        splitAttrString: function(theStr) {
            var attrs = [];

            var RefString = function(s) {
                this.value = s;
            };
            RefString.prototype.toString = function() {
                return this.value;
            };
            RefString.prototype.charAt = String.prototype.charAt;
            var data = new RefString(theStr);

            var getBlock = function(endChr, restString) {
                var block = '';
                var currChr = '';
                while ((currChr != endChr) && (restString.value !== '')) {
                    if (/'|"/.test(currChr)) {
                        block = $.trim(block) + getBlock(currChr, restString);
                    }
                    else if (/\{/.test(currChr)) {
                        block = $.trim(block) + getBlock('}', restString);
                    }
                    else if (/\[/.test(currChr)) {
                        block = $.trim(block) + getBlock(']', restString);
                    }
                    else {
                        block += currChr;
                    }
                    currChr = restString.charAt(0);
                    restString.value = restString.value.slice(1);
                }
                return $.trim(block);
            };

            do {
                var attr = getBlock(',', data);
                attrs.push(attr);
            }
            while (data.value !== '')
                ;
            return attrs;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This works great with numbers also and we don't have to run a separate parseInt loop for them as mentioned in another answer below. This is real deep thinking. Appreciate it very much and I think the best answer among all !!

Comment: Your code is useful, but you didn't answer the question: *"Is there anything built-in to do this?"* Of course we can write a custom function as you did, or even better import one of the many existing libraries already written and well tested (e.g. [jquery-csv](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Parsing-Displaying-CSV-Files-jQuery.html)). But is there something ***built in?***

Answer (score 31):

The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.

```
var array = string.split(',');
```

Comment: what would the outcome be? for example if i have var a = "hello,world,baby"; and var array = a.split(','); --> would my array look like this: array = ["hello","world","baby"]; ??

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The resulting array would be just as you mention.

Answer (score 25):

#### Upgraded `str.split(',')`

The simple `str.split(',')` doesn't have much smarts. Here are some upgrades for different needs. You can customize the functionality to your heart's content.

```js
const str = "a, b,c,  d  ,e  ,f,,g"
const num = "1, 2,3,  4  ,5  ,6,,7.495"
const mix = "a, 2,3,  d  ,5  ,f,,7.495,g"

console.log(    str.split(',')
) // spaces NOT trimmed, empty values included
  // ["a", " b", "c", "  d  ", "e  ", "f", "", "g"] 

console.log(    str.split(/[ ,]+/)
) // spaces trimmed, empty values skipped
  // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"] 

console.log(    str.split(/\s*,\s*/)
) // spaces trimmed, empty values NOT skipped
  // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "", "g"]

console.log(    num.split(',').map(Number)
) // numbers, empty values default to zero
  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7.495] 

console.log(    num.split(/[ ,]+/).map(Number)
) // numbers, skips empty values
  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.495]

console.log(    mix.split(/\s*,\s*/)
                .map(x => (x === '') ? '' : (isNaN(Number(x)) ? x : Number(x)) )
) // mixed values, empty values included
  // ["a", 2, 3, "d", 5, "f", "", 7.495, "g"]
```

#### Using `JSON.parse`

It may feel like a bit of a hack, but it's simple and highly optimized by most Javascript engines.

It has some other advantages such as support for nested lists. But there are disadvantages, such as requiring the input to be properly formatted JSON.

By using `string.replace` similar to how I used `string.split` above, you can fix the input. In the first two examples below, I customize how I want empty values handled:

```js
const num = "1, 2,3,  4  ,5  ,6,,7.495"
const mix = "a, 2,3,  d  ,5  ,f,7.495,g"

console.log(    JSON.parse('['+num.replace(/,\s*,/,',0,')+']')
) // numbers, empty values default to zero
  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7.495]

console.log(    JSON.parse('['+num.replace(/,\s*,/,',')+']')
) // numbers, skips empty values
  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.495]

console.log(    JSON.parse('['+mix.replace(/(^|,)\s*([^,]*[^0-9, ][^,]*?)\s*(?=,|$)/g,'$1"$2"')+']') 
) // mixed values, will ERROR on empty values
  // ["a", 2, 3, "d", 5, "f", "7.495", "g"]
```

Answer (score 19):

Note that the following:

```
var a = "";
var x = new Array();
x = a.split(",");
alert(x.length);
```

will alert 1

Answer (score 15):

Pass your comma-separated string into this function and it will return an array, and if a comma-separated string is not found then it will return null.

```
function splitTheString(CommaSepStr) {
    var ResultArray = null;

    // Check if the string is null or so.
    if (CommaSepStr!= null) {

        var SplitChars = ',';

        // Check if the string has comma of not will go to else
        if (CommaSepStr.indexOf(SplitChars) >= 0) {
            ResultArray = CommaSepStr.split(SplitChars);

        }
        else {

            // The string has only one value, and we can also check
            // the length of the string or time and cross-check too.
            ResultArray = [CommaSepStr];
        }
    }
    return ResultArray;
}
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: This is the most correct solution if you aren't sure the string will contain your split value.

This function will keep the split method from erroring out if the string doesn't have a comma (given the above example).

Comment: Note: functions that start with a capital letter are, most of the time, designed to be invoked. best to use lower case letters on functions that are not designed to be invoked.

Comment: This failed for me when I had only one value with no commas. Added `else { ResultArray = [CommaSepStr]; }` after the second `if`

Answer (score 12):

Here is a function that will convert a string to an array, even if there is only one item in the list (no separator character):

```
function listToAray(fullString, separator) {
  var fullArray = [];

  if (fullString !== undefined) {
    if (fullString.indexOf(separator) == -1) {
      fullArray.push(fullString);
    } else {
      fullArray = fullString.split(separator);
    }
  }

  return fullArray;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var myString = 'alpha,bravo,charlie,delta';
var myArray = listToArray(myString, ',');
myArray[2]; // charlie

var yourString = 'echo';
var yourArray = listToArray(yourString, ',');
yourArray[0]; // echo
```

Comment: No error is thrown if the separator is not found: `'echo'.split(',')` returns `['echo']`, and  `''.split(',')`  returns `['']`.  You _will_ get an error if you call `x.split(',')` when `x` is not a string (including when `x` is _undefined_ or _null_), because there is no `split` function available for other types.

Comment: Ah, I see that I was in fact trying to use `split` for an undefined object when I wrote up my listToArray function. Thanks for pointing that out...

Answer (score 9):

```
let str = "January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December"

let arr = str.split(',');
```

it will result:

```
["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
```

and if you want to convert following to:

```
["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
```

this:

```
"January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December";
```

use:

```
str = arr.join(',')
```

Answer (score 8):

### Return function

```
var array = (new Function("return [" + str+ "];")());
```

Its accept string and objectstrings:

```
var string = "0,1";

var objectstring = '{Name:"Tshirt", CatGroupName:"Clothes", Gender:"male-female"}, {Name:"Dress", CatGroupName:"Clothes", Gender:"female"}, {Name:"Belt", CatGroupName:"Leather", Gender:"child"}';

var stringArray = (new Function("return [" + string+ "];")());

var objectStringArray = (new Function("return [" + objectstring+ "];")());
```

JSFiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/7ne9L4Lj/1/

Comment: text strings are having errors - SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
number strings are ok.
eg. 
`var stringtext = "String, text, I, am"; 
var stringtextArray = (new Function("return [" + string text + "];")());`

result is: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue, but more complex as I needed to transform a CSV file into an array of arrays (each line is one array element that inside has an array of items split by comma).

The easiest solution (and more secure I bet) was to use [PapaParse](http://papaparse.com/) which has a "no-header" option that transform the CSV file into an array of arrays, plus, it automatically detected the "," as my delimiter.

Plus, it is registered in [Bower](https://bower.io/), so I only had to:

```
bower install papa-parse --save
```

And then use it in my code as follows:

```
var arrayOfArrays = Papa.parse(csvStringWithEnters), {header:false}).data;
```

I really liked it.

Answer (score 3):

As @oportocala mentions, an empty string will not result in the expected empty array.

So to counter, do:

```
str
.split(',')
.map(entry => entry.trim())
.filter(entry => entry)
```

For an array of expected integers, do:

```
str
.split(',')
.map(entry => parseInt(entry))
.filter(entry => typeof entry ==='number')
```

Answer (score 3):

**Easiest way to do it:**

```
let myStr = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8';

const stringToArr = (myStr) => {
    return myStr.split(',').map(x => x.trim());
};
```

Answer (score 2):

A good solution for that:

```
let obj = ['A','B','C']

obj.map((c) => { return c. }).join(', ')
```

Answer (score 1):

### Shortest

```
str.split`,`
```

```js
var str = "January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December";

let arr = str.split`,`;

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: What is up with literal backticks? What is the explanation?

Comment: here is some info about [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

```
let myString = "January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December";
      const temp=myString .split(",");
      console.log(temp);
```

Output:-
 ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

Very simple you can use the **split** default javascript function for this.

Answer (score 0):

I made php script to convert string to array, and you can run it into your browser, so is easy

```
<form method="POST">
    <div>
        <label>String</label> <br>
        <input name="string" type="text">
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 1rem;">
        <button>konvert</button>
    </div>
</form>

<?php

$string = @$_POST['string'];

if ($string) {
    $result = json_encode(explode(",",$string));
    echo " '$result' <br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user makes a typo by adding an extra space. You could use something like this.

```
tags: foo,  zar, gar
```

```
const stringToArr = (string) => {
  return string.trim.split(",");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question but I didn't see any answers for more complex cases then `1,2,3` (expect one but it was written in jQuery), so here is my solution in plain JS:

```js
function csvRowToArray(str, seperator, block) {
  const columns = [];
  let column = '',
      findNextBlock = false;
    for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let letter = str[i];
    if (letter === seperator && !findNextBlock) {
      columns.push(column);
      column = '';
      continue;
    }
    
    column += letter;
    
    if (letter === block && str[i - 1] != '\\') {
      findNextBlock = !findNextBlock;
    }
  }
  columns.push(column);
  
  return columns;
}
```

And with string like this: `165020,"Unijne logo produkcji ekologicznej, tzw. “Eko liść”","hi said \\"Hello\\" to me",DE-ÖKO-003,1/31/2025`

The result is:

```json
[
  "165020",
  "Unijne logo produkcji ekologicznej, tzw. “Eko liść”",
  "hi said \"Hello\" to me",
  "DE-ÖKO-003",
  "1/31/2025"
]
```

Answer (score -2):

For an array of strings to a comma-separated string:

```
let months = ["January","Feb"];
let monthsString = months.join(", ");
```

Comment: That's the reverse of what they're asking for

Comment: @camille i know that did u read the text i said "For an array of strings to a comma-separated string"

Comment: Yes, I did read the text of your answer, but I also read the text of the question. What you've provided is an answer to the opposite operation of what they're trying to do. It would be a fine answer to a question on joining an array, but that's not what this question is