# How to get public array In HTML file which is initialize in .cs file of web app?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html

Рow to get the array in HTML file added from some side initialize in .cs file? Hope for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not provide enough info. I will assume you mean the codebehind file (c#) when you say .cs file (what else is there to assume?) and your array is added in c#, which you want to access in js

Register your array as a string literal as script block

something like:

```
string myArr = "; var myArr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]; "; //putting your array in a string
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), myArr, true);
```

now in your html file, you can access them with javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 alert(myArr[2]); //will alert 3
</script>
```

For 2D arrays,

```
var myArr = [[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]]; //2D array
alert(myArr[0]); //    to access 1st row: [0,0]
alert(myArr[0][0]); // to access 1st row 1st column: 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply u are right that it is a c# .cs code behind file and my array name "string terms" its 2D array then it would be as same as you mentioned above?

Comment: Hi @Forums Forall, please look at the edit. It's exactly the same way, though the access will be slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

- Send array (via GET) as comma separated list, e.g. `Static.html?arr=1,2,3,4`
- Read query string using JavaScript, e.g. [jQuery Query Object](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object)
- Parse it into an array, e.g. [string.split()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-javascript-comma-separated-string-into-an-array)