# How To Pass Arguments In Jquery Function C# Web Application?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i am drawing chart using High Chart JS in my web app in which data values are hardcoded as shown below,

```
function Drawgraph(){
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            zoomType: 'x',
            spacingRight: 20
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Power to USD '
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' :
                'Drag your finger over the plot to zoom in'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            maxZoom: 14 * 24 * 3600000, // fourteen days
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Power rate'
            },
            min: 0.6,
            startOnTick: false,
            showFirstLabel: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true                    
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
                    stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.theme.colors[0]],
                        [1, 'rgba(2,0,0,0)']
                    ]
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                            radius: 5
                        }
                    }
                },
                shadow: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1                        
                    }
                }
            }
        },  
        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'Power to USD',
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2011, 0, 01),
            data: [
                0.8446, 0.8445, 0.8444, 0.8451, 0.8418, 0.8264, 0.8258, 0.8232, 0.8233, 0.8258, 
                0.8283, 0.8278, 0.8256, 0.8292, 0.8239, 0.8239, 0.8245, 0.8265, 0.8261, 0.8269, 
                0.7095
            ]
        }]
    }); 
});
};
```

How would i pass values to the data [] ?? from array [] term ...

Hopes for your reply

Regards,

Comment: @Kieren Not the best answer, but the best CORRECT answer. Marking a question answered makes no sense if the answer is not correct. It would be misleading.

Comment: By the way: why are people voting this down?  The question itself is clear and concise.   If you don't understand the question, then go find another one to look at.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get public array In HTML file which is initialize in .cs file of web app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608192/how-to-get-public-array-in-html-file-which-is-initialize-in-cs-file-of-web-app)

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone you seem to be more professional ans intelligent then me i hope you know that when i do not have enough reputation that is "15" to up and down the click the answer then how would i Tick the answer but you are right that those who have power of reputation to tick the answer they i think miss use it them there isn't any reason for tick this question in a negative side !

Comment: @Kornelije Petak,  Kieren Johnstone  is right i have got many correct answer of my question but i do apologies for those people who cooperate a lot but cant tick there answer due to my reputation

Comment: @Forums I didn't mean that there are no correct answers on your questions. I haven't had time to take a look at them. I was just pointing out that the answers that do not solve the OP problem should not be marked correct. It's not directed toward you, or anyone else in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your CS code:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("DataArray", "0.8, 0.5, 1.6");
```