# How to pass the Array In jquery from C# code C# application?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

hi how to pass array while array is,

```
double[] A={0.8446, 0.8445, 0.8444, 0.8451};
```

from c# code to Jquery i am trying like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function Drawgraph( ){
            var chart;  
            alert ("<%= A %>");
                series: [{
                        type: 'area',
                        name: 'Power to USD',
                        //pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                        //pointStart: Date.UTC(2011, 0, 01),
                        point:Arr,
                        data: Arr
```

Hopes for help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Pass Arguments In Jquery Function C# Web Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649884/how-to-pass-arguments-in-jquery-function-c-web-application)

Comment: Didn't I answer this yesterday...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and write it out into a Javascript variable:

```
var data = <%new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(A)%>
```

Outputs:

```
var data = [0.8446,0.8445,0.8444,0.8451];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `JSON` for this. Check out the [website](http://www.json.org/) for more information.

You can use the `JavaScriptSerializer` to achieve what you are after.

```
[WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
public object GetDoubles()
{
   return new { 0.8446, 0.8445, 0.8444, 0.8451 };
}
```

To get this to your client use `JQuery AJAX`

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'SomeService.asmx/GetDoubles',
   type: 'GET',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   success: function(data){
      // access using data (or data.d)
      $(data.d).each(function(){
          alert(this);
      });
   }
});
```