# Why is the comma-separated string not converting to an array using split() in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to convert a comma separated string into an array using the split method([Convert comma separated string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-javascript-comma-separated-string-into-an-array)).

This is the code:

```
var nameList = "milk,sugar,flour";
var nameArray = nameList.split(',');

document.write('The nameList is: ' + nameList);
document.write('<br />');
document.write('The nameArray is: ' + nameArray);
```

This is the output:

> The nameList is: milk,sugar,flour
>  The nameArray is:
>   milk,sugar,flour

It looks to me like it is still a string separated by commas. Why is the comma-separated string not converting to an array using split() in javaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an array. `Array#toString` produces the comma-separated output.

Try this:

```
[3, 4, 'b'].toString();
```

If you use `console.log` instead of `document.write` to inspect `nameArray`, you'll see that it is an array.

Answer (score 0):

thats the way how JAVASCRIPT shoes an array

it **did** convert it

**but** you told JS to display it

so thats what he does.

proof:

```
nameArray[0]====>milk

nameArray[1]====>sugar
```

Answer (score 0):

When you implicitly convert the array to a string by appending it to a string, it displays the array.toString() which uses commas. You can override this if you want.

if you do this instead, it will show the properly annotated version.

```
 JSON.stringify( nameArray ,"\t")
```