# How to convert comma separated string into numeric array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a one-dimensional array of integer in JavaScript that I'd like to add data from comma separated string, Is there a simple way to do this?

e.g : `var strVale = "130,235,342,124 ";`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-javascript-comma-separated-string-into-an-array

Answer (score 48):

```
? "123,87,65".split(",").map(Number)
> [123, 87, 65]
```

*Edit* >>

Thanks to *@NickN* & *@connexo* remarks! 
**A filter** is applicable if you by eg. want to exclude any non-numeric values:

```
?", ,0,,6, 45,x78,94c".split(",").filter(x => x.trim().length && !isNaN(x)).map(Number)
> [0, 6, 45]
```

Comment: This is slick! Best answer so far.

Comment: Very nice answer. If you want to exclude any non-numeric values, you can tack on a filter for NaN's:

`"123,87,hello,65".split(",").map(Number).filter(x => !isNaN(x))` gives 
`[123, 87, 65]`.

Comment: This fails for `",,1,".split(",").map(Number).filter(x => !isNaN(x))` as it will return `[0, 0, 1, 0]`. This is due to `Number("")` returning `0`. Also note that `isNaN("")` returns `false`.

Comment: @connexo, you can easily fix it via `",,1,".split(",").map(Number).filter(x => x!="" && !isNaN(x))`

Comment: @Serge No, you cannot as it will rule out `0` values. Try `",,0,".split(",").map(Number).filter(x => x!="" && !isNaN(x))` https://stackoverflow.com/a/56426645/3744304 solves this.

Answer (score 29):

You can use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get string array from comma separated string. If you iterate and perform mathematical operation on element of string array then that element will be treated as number by run-time cast but still you have string array. To convert comma separated string int array see the **edit**.

```
arr = strVale.split(',');
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LsavnLwa/)

```
var strVale = "130,235,342,124";
arr = strVale.split(',');
for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
    console.log(arr[i] + " * 2 = " + (arr[i])*2);
```

**Output**

```
130 * 2 = 260
235 * 2 = 470
342 * 2 = 684
124 * 2 = 248
```

**Edit, Comma separated string to int Array** In the above example the string are casted to numbers in expression but to get the int array from string array you need to convert it to number.

```
var strVale = "130,235,342,124";
var strArr = strVale.split(',');
var intArr = [];
for(i=0; i < strArr.length; i++)
   intArr.push(parseInt(strArr[i]));
```

Comment: this is wrong / just one step to the actual solution. It'll save the numbers as strings to the array, not as integers!

Comment: this does not covert values to INT as OP asked

Comment: I have updated my answer, you both are right. Although the example shows string array element converted to number due to expression but array is of string not numbers.

Comment: Now try this for `var strVale = "130,,,0,,235,342,124";`.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [String `split` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get the single numbers as an array of strings. Then [convert them to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1133770/1048572) with the unary plus operator, the `Number` function or `parseInt`, and add them to your array:

```
var arr = [1,2,3],
    strVale = "130,235,342,124 ";
var strings = strVale.split(",");
for (var i=0; i<strVale.length; i++)
    arr.push( + strings[i] );
```

Or, in one step, using [Array `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert them and [applying](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) them to one single `push`:

```
arr.push.apply(arr, strVale.split(",").map(Number));
```

Answer (score 12):

just you need to use couple of methods for this, that's it!

```
var strVale = "130,235,342,124";
var resultArray = strVale.split(',').map(function(strVale){return Number(strVale);});
```

the output will be the array of numbers.

Comment: not bad, but see my answer for a less verbose way to do it ;)

Answer (score 3):

The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.

```
Syntax:
  string.split(separator,limit)


arr =  strVale.split(',');
```

[**SEE HERE**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Answer (score 3):

You can split and convert like

```
 var strVale = "130,235,342,124 ";
 var intValArray=strVale.split(',');
 for(var i=0;i<intValArray.length;i++{
     intValArray[i]=parseInt(intValArray[i]);
}
```

Now you can use intValArray in you logic.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
var answerInt = [];
var answerString = "1,2,3,4";
answerString.split(',').forEach(function (item) {
   answerInt.push(parseInt(item))
});
```

Comment: That's not a string.

Comment: @delroh Yep changed, Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

All of the given answers so far create a possibly unexpected result for a string like `",1,0,-1,,  ,,2"`:

```js
",1,0,-1,,  ,,2".split(",").map(Number).filter(x => !isNaN(x))
// [0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```

To solve this, I've come up with the following fix:

```js
",1,0,-1,,  ,,2".split(',').filter(x => x.trim() !== "").map(Number).filter(x => !isNaN(x))
// [1, 0, -1, 2]
```

Please note that due to

```
isNaN("") // false!
```

and

```
isNaN(" ") // false
```

we cannot combine both filter steps.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy and quick solution when the string value is proper with the comma(,).

But if the string is with the last character with the comma, Which makes a blank array element, and this is also removed extra spaces around it.

> "123,234,345,"

So I suggest using `push()`

```
var arr = [], str="123,234,345,"
str.split(",").map(function(item){
    if(item.trim()!=''){arr.push(item.trim())}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are good solutions in this post but I would like to add one more. Instead of using `filter` and `map` I would suggest to use `reduce` to iterate through all the items just once.

Also I will compare it with the use of a regex looking for digits. Please evaluate which method fits your needs. Here are the examples:

```js
const strA = ',1,0,-2,a3 , 4b,a5b ,21, 6 7,, 8.1'

const arrayOfNumbersA = strA.split(',').reduce((acc, val) => val && !Number.isNaN(+val) ? acc.push(+val) && acc : acc, [])
console.log(arrayOfNumbersA)

// => [1, 0, -2, 21, 8.1] - As you can see in the output the negative numbers 
// do work and if the number have characters before or after
// the numbers are removed from since they are treated like NaN. 
// Note: in this case the comma is the delimiting each number that will be evaluated in the reduce

const arrayOfNumbersB = strA.match(/[\d.]+/g).map(Number)
console.log(arrayOfNumbersB)

// => [1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 21, 6, 7, 8.1] - As you can see in the output the negative numbers
// are transformed to positives and if the number have characters before or after
// the numbers placed any way. 
//Note: that in this case the regex is looking for digits no matter how they are separated.

// FYI: seeing all the steps using the reduce method
const arrayOfNumbersC = strA.split(',').reduce((acc, val) => {
  if(val && !Number.isNaN(+val)) {
    acc.push(+val)
  }
  
  return acc
 }, []) 
  
console.log(arrayOfNumbersC)
// => [1, 0, -2, 21, 8.1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to also take string value and avoid crushing we can solve it this way

```
 let strVale = "130,235,342,124 ";
 let unformattedArray =strVale.split(',');

 const formatArray = (unformattedArray) => {
    if (unformattedArray.map(Number).includes(NaN)) {
    return unformattedArray;
}
else {
  return unformattedArray.map(Number);
}
}
    
  //then every time we want to format we call our function to format for us
 console.log(formatArray(unformattedArray));
 // or asign a value

  let foramttedArray =  formatArray(unformattedArray);
```