# String with Comma separated numbers to array of integer in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I am converting String with Comma separated numbers to a array of integer like,

```
 var string = "1,2,3,4"; 
 var array = string.replace(/, +/g, ",").split(",").map(Number);
```

it returns `array = [1,2,3,4];`

But when ,

```
 var string = ""; 
 var array = string.replace(/, +/g, ",").split(",").map(Number);
```

it returns `array = [0];`

I was expecting it to return `array = [];`
can someone say why this is happening.

Comment: you forget replace after string.

Comment: `.split()` always returns at least one element.

Comment: Edited, So I suppose I have to add a check whether string is empty or not then only split it .

Comment: related: [How to convert comma separated string into numeric array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16396124/1048572)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would recommend this:

```
var array;
if (string.length === 0) {
    array = new Array();
} else {
    array = string.replace(/, +/g, ",").split(",").map(Number);
}
```

Comment: Thx RGraham, exactly what I wanted. (my first answer)

Comment: As according to this answer I ended up doing --> array = (string.length === 0) ? new Array() : string.replace(/, +/g, ",").split(",").map(Number);

Comment: much more elegant (y)

Comment: It looks like you are missing the 'replace': array = string.replace(/, +/g, ",").split(",").map(Number);

Answer (score 4):

The `string.replace(/, +/g, ",").split(",")` returns an array with one item - an empty string. In javascript, empty string when converted to number is 0. See yourself

```
Number(""); // returns (int)0
```

Comment: you forget replace after string same as OP.

Comment: Ya I got that now .Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To remove the spaces after the comma you can use regular expressions inside the split function itself.

```
array = string.split(/\s*,\s*/).map(Number);
```

*I hope it will help*