# Convert word list into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, cpu-word

I've tried to see if there were any scripts to convert a list of words into an array and I can't seem to find one.

Anyone know where I can find one?

Input:

```
Dog
Cat
Hamster
```

Gets converted to

```
["Dog", "Cat", "Hamster"]
```

Noo.. this isn't what I mean. I have a txt file with a bunch of words on each line and I was wondering if there was something out there already created that can convert each word into an array.

Comment: what do you mean by list, is it string `"Dog\nCat\nHamster"`?

Comment: How do you input them? Try `push` in an array.

Comment: I mean like a text area and it takes every word and puts them into an array. (1400 words converted into an array). No it's just plain text, no strings

Comment: How are they delimited ? Comma? space? Line Feed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert comma separated string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on the string.

For example:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('list');
var arr = [];
textarea.addEventListener('input', function () {
    arr = this.value.split('\n');
    console.log(arr);
}, false);
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/tacixu/1/edit)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the string is actually `"Dog\nCat\nHamster"` then just do

```
"Dog\nCat\nHamster".split('\n');//returns ["Dog", "Cat", "Hamster"]
```

For a TextArea try this

```
myTextArea.value.split('\n'); // it will return desired output.
```

Where `myTextArea` is the TextArea you can get using `getElement`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for a `textarea` input is using the `match()` function of javascript like this:

```
var words = []
$('textarea').on('blur', function(){
    words = $(this).val().match(/\w+/g)
    alert(words)
})
```

[here a fiddle of it working.](http://jsfiddle.net/ntHKW/1/)

This doesn't need for the words to be in different lines.