# Convert list of words into array?

Tags: atom-editor

I have a very long list of words like this in the [Atom](https://atom.io/) editor

```
car
cat 
dog
town
```

I would like to convert this with Atom into an array like this:

```
['car', 'cat', 'dog', 'town']
```

It is easy to create a `'` on the left of all words by putting the cursor left to `car` and then pressing alt+shitf+arrow_down till one reaches `town` and then pressing `'`. For the right, the best thing I found is to to click at the end of each word with the mouse and pressing control till all cursors are set. Then just add `',` and backspace. This gives me

```
'car', 'cat', 'dog', 'town'
```

but its very cumbersome for a very long list. Is there a better method to this task in Atom?

Comment: I think it was already covered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076300/convert-word-list-into-array

Comment: @idontknowcoding this question is asking if this task is possible to achieve in atom. The question that you refere to is asking for a script that does it. I should make it more clear that this is atom specific. I only had the tag.

Comment: Does atom support multi-cursors? In Sublime it would something like: Ctrl-A, Ctrl-Shift-J, Home, "'", End, "', ", Delete then fixup the start and end (finger memory isn't perfect :|)

Comment: @user2864740 yes atom does support multi-cursors. Ctrl+A will select everything and Shift+J just replaces everything with capital J ^^

Comment: @Adam It would in Sublime too, needs the Ctrl. Now I'm curious, downloading Atom :D

Comment: @user2864740 hm, ctrl+shift+J does unfortunately do nothing in atom

Comment: @Adam Same sequence works in Atom - just have to use the menu to enter multi-cursor-mode (or setup a binding, perhaps..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a just-downloaded Atom, I was able to use the following sequence.

The "Split Into Lines" does not appear to have a default keybinding, although once setup it would be possible to perform the (somewhat long) sequence of steps sans-Menu.

- Ctrl+A - *selects all*
- Menu -> Selection -> Split Into Lines
- Home - *moves all cursors to the start/end of each line and wrap*
- '
- End
- ',Space
- Delete - *collapses lines*
- Home - *change back to single-cursor mode and select entire line*
- Shift-End
- [ - *this auto-bracketed the selected text "['car', ..., 'town', ]"*
- End - *now tidy up the the ", " before the end "]"*
- Left-Arrow
- Backspace
- Backspace

Not quite as short as a regex-replace.. adapt and/or take concepts as useful. Multi-cursor mode is incredibly powerful in certain cases.

Comment: What do you mean with `menu multi-select` ? I only have `File`, `Edit`, `View`, `Selection`, `Find` `Packages` and `Help` in my menu.

Comment: "Menu -> Selection -> Split Into Lines" - no extra packages. I just downloaded whatever was "Windows 64-bit installer".

Comment: Ah perfect, that was exaclty the kind of instructions that I wished for. Actually after clicking `split into lines` I can directly insert `'` which will put single quotes on both ends of every line.

Answer (score 2):

Use the find & replace function with the regex option.

Replace new lines `\n` with `','`, for example.

[image: how to use the find&replace function with regex option]