# How To Create Array of Arrays? [ ["a","b","c"] , ["c","d","e"] ]

Tags: javascript

Hello I have several strings like this:

```
Name,Age,Location and Jon,20,London
```

How can I turn these strings into an array of arrays like so:
Not sure if the correct term is a multidimensional array or Jagged array...

```
[["Name","Age","Location"],["Jon","20","London"]]
```

What I Tried:

I looked into doing Javascript string split and .push, but no success.

```
var a = "Name,Age,Location" ;
var b = "Jon,20,London";
a.push(b);
```

What Worked (I was stuck at the .split part, Please see answer from "Sam"):

```
var a = 'Name,Age,Location'.split(',');
var b = 'Jon,20,London'.split(',');
var c = [];

c.push(a)
c.push(b)
console.log(JSON.stringify(c)) 
// [["Name","Age","Location"],["Jon","20","London"]]
```

Comment: You're not looking for `input.split(" and ").map(function(str) { return str.split(","); })`, are you?

Comment: Put your efforts here, is it static or dynamic?

Comment: How did you try to apply `.split()`, because that would be the right method to use.

Comment: Your question must be more clear. You said 'You have several strings like this ...'. We need to know what that exactly means. You have these strings where exactly?

Comment: Half of your question has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array

Comment: I used a nodejs/js module and it parses a csv file giving me a comma separated text, Name,Age,Location. It looks like an array, but I wanted to combine an array in an array. Concat combines them and the strings are already comma separated so not sure if split is still useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How To Push Array into Array?

Given your code:

```
var a = "Name,Age,Location" ;
var b = "Jon,20,London";
a.push(b);
```

Here, both `a` and `b` are strings, not arrays; turning a string into an array using comma as the delimiter is simple, though:

```
var a = 'Name,Age,Location'.split(',');
var b = 'Jon,20,London'.split(',');
a.push(b);
```

Doing this will yield the following array:

```
['Name','Age','Location',['Jon',20,'London']]
```

Almost there; now you just need a separate array to put both `a` and `b` into:

```
var c = [a, b];
// or
var c = []; c.push(a); c.push(b);
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, im updating my post with what worked. Thanks.