# How to convert a string of comma separated values into data array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm using Charts.js, I wonder how to convert a string of comma separated values into data array.

There a response data, it would return (I already coded for formatting):

```
100.00
65.89
244.47
244.46
314.99
320.30
314.99
319.63
```

Then I save this data as var after of AJAX response (with jQuery):

```
var dataComissions;
$.each(data.orders, function(i, item) {
    var dataComissions = data.orders[i].commission;     
});
```

This data has line break each value, I need excepted result like this as one string with commas:

```
100.00, 65.89, 244.47, 244.46, 314.99, 320.30, 314.99, 319.63
```

**EDIT:** These answers that I'm not looking, because I can't get one var with separated values, I need to convert it.

This is console.log what i got

[image: data response]

I need to convert this response data into a var like this:

```
320.30, 100.00, 65.89, 65.89, 65.89, 244.47, 244.46 ...
```

**EDIT 2:** Request data was used with:

```
$.getJSON( "orders/list", function( data, status ) {

        }).done(function(data) {
           $.each(data.orders, function(i, item) {
           console.warn(data.orders[i].commission); //This is from screenshot
           var dataComissions = data.orders[i].commission;  
});
```

@Vega

```
var commisions = [];    
$.getJSON( "phrapi/orders/list", function( data, status ) {


        }).done(function(data) {
//    console.warn(data.orders[0].created_at);


var commisions = [];
$.each(data.orders, function(i, item) {
  commisions.push(item.commision);
});

console.log(commisions.join(', '));
});
```

result of console:

[image]

Comment: The [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function may be what you're looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert comma separated string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array)

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki That's not duplicated, different behavior

Comment: Question is lacking information. How are you getting that console? Where is the log statements coming from?

Comment: @epascarello Updated question, look EDIT 2

Comment: @Ivan You have a `$.each` inside a `$.each`... can you get rid of one of them..

Comment: @Vega oops, edited, updated console result

Comment: @Ivan There is a typo in the property name. The property name should be `item.commission`.. The typo is actually there in my answer and since you copied it.. you copied the typo too :)

Comment: @Vega arrrghhhh you trolled me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improvised with an array. Maintaining in an array would add the flexibility to modify later if needed.

```js
//your ajax respose ignoring the other fields
var data = {orders: [{commision: 320.30}, {commision: 100.00}, {commision: 65.89}, {commision: 65.89}, {commision: 65.89}, {commision: 244.47}, {commision: 244.46}]};

var commisions = [];
$.each(data.orders, function(i, item) {
  commisions.push(item.commision);
});
//use commisions.join(', ') to join the array to a single string seperated by a comma and a space

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = commisions.join(', ');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Based on your second edit: Reformatted based on the input data. You may need to set it to an string object outside the loop.

```js
//your ajax respose ignoring the other fields
var data = {orders: [{commision: 320.30}, {commision: 100.00}, {commision: 65.89}, {commision: 65.89}, {commision: 65.89}, {commision: 244.47}, {commision: 244.46}]};

var resultString = '';
$.each(data.orders, function(i, item) {
  resultString += item.commision + ((i == (data.orders.length - 1))? "":", ");
});

document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = resultString;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result1"></div>
```

<s>If I understood your edited post correctly: You could just replace the line break in the response string with a ", " (comma and a space) using `.replace` like below,</s>

```js
var stringWithLineBreaks = document.getElementById("ajaxResponse").value;
var formattedString = stringWithLineBreaks.replace(/\n/g, ", ");
console.log(formattedString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="ajaxResponse">100.00
65.89
244.47
244.46
314.99
320.30
314.99
319.63</textarea>
```

Comment: It doesn't help me because how I am supposed to make arrayOfValues at first place if my response data returns value each line in loop?

Comment: @Ivan Used an array instead of string which would allow you to change the delimiter in the join with a slight change where it is needed.

Comment: @Ivan Are you pushing "comments" instead of "commision". That image shows the items getting added to arrow is not commision but an empty string in that object.

Comment: @Ivan Yes, I see that.. but What I am saying is that there is no way for you to get empty commas (, , , , , ) as you had shown in the above comment unless you are pushing a different element instead of commission. Check what var you are pushing at line `commisions.push(item.commision);` in your code when you got that console output.

Comment: Did you notice your var data, their properties have no quotes? It should be {"orders": [{"commision": 320.30}, ... ] } Try it

Comment: @Ivan You don't need quotes for property name in JS however JSON response always serializes with quotes as it is required in other languages.

Comment: Still got empty values, I totally copied your snippet in my repo, I swear

Comment: @Ivan Could you post what you had copied in your question? including the `console.log`. Thanks.

Comment: Added, look my question where starts @Vega

Answer (score 3):

use [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split based on a delimiter, so

```
var string_of_values = '100.00, 65.89, 244.47, 244.46, 314.99, 320.30, 314.99, 319.63';

var arr = string_of_values.split(', '); // this says, "split my string into an array, dividing each element by ', '. Note the whitespace is included here.

console.log(arr); // outputs: ["100.00", "65.89", "244.47", "244.46", "314.99", "320.30", "314.99", "319.63"]
```

http://jsbin.com/rebirigeyu/edit?html,js,console

**EDIT**

based on your edit, do this:

```
var dataComissions = ''; // stores the result of concat
$.getJSON( "orders/list", function( data, status ) {

        }).done(function(data) {
           $.each(data.orders, function(i, item) {
           if (data.orders[i].commission) { 
               dataComissions += data.orders[i].commission+', ';   // add to our store
            }
});
console.warn(dataComissions); //This is from screenshot
```

The problem is you were re-setting `dataComissions` each time, instead of appending your value.

the `if()` block makes sure there is a value in `commission` before setting it. this prevents undefined value from showing up.

Comment: so you're trying to format it as a string? so concatenate each value together with a comma seperating?

Comment: yes, concantenating each value togheter with a comma separating, also edited my question again, look EDIT 2

Comment: It works but how to get rid of "undefined"  screenshot of console: http://i.imgur.com/T5jZ4MJ.png

Comment: the very first item in `data.orders` (the `[0]` index), does not have a value for commission. Please see my edit

Comment: If you want your answer gets accepted, please fix how to avoid this bad loop. Thanks!

Comment: @Ivan console.log outside of the loop. you're seeing each addition because the log is inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use string method [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

E.x. you have a string.

```
    let string = "split,a,string";
    let arrayOfStrings = string.split(',');
```

arrayOfStrings will be ["split", "a", "string"].

Comment: This is just duplicating a comment made to the original question.