# Split 1 input text field into 3 text input fields with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a text input field like this:

someone types = `22x32x5`

Is it possible to extract this value into 3 different text input fields without the x in jQuery? And how?

```
FieldB=22
FieldC=32
FieldD=5
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert comma separated string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done using the 'split' command and then putting the array elements in the relevant fields:

```
array=input.split('x');
$('#input1').val(array[0]);
.....
```

Here is a working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uv3p8dwh/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with the function `split()` it splits a string into an array, use this code:

```
var types = "22x32x5";
var temp = new Array();
// this will return an array with strings "22", "32", "5", etc.
temp = types .split("x");

for (a in temp ) {
     // Your Code here to populate to input field. You will get the value from temp[a].
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
var string =  '22x32x5';
var newstring = string.split('x');
 $('#FieldB').val(newstring[0]);
 $('#FieldC').val(newstring[1]);
 $('#FieldD').val(newstring[2]);
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7ne9L4Lj/19/)**