# Convert string to array number Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have something like this in JavaScript

```
var stringArray = "[[1088163336,80],[1088154636,95],[1088150436,75]]"
```

And I need this

```
var array = [[1088163336,80],[1088154636,95],[1088150436,75]];
```

Help please.

Comment: [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: you can use `stringArray.split(',')` in a similar way to [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var sampleArray = JSON.parse(stringArray);
```