# What is wrong with this regex for comma-separated string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to convert a comma or semicolon separated string into an array, but handling before conversion several omission from users (double commas, space after comma or semicolon).  In the example:

```
myStr = "item1, item2,,, this is item3; item4 , "
```

I want to get:

```
myArray = ["item1", "item2", "this is item3", "item4"]
```

My actual regex is:

```
myArray = myStr.split(/[(,\s);,]+/);
```

But, although I'm adding parenthesis to the combination comma-space `(,\s)` the regex are catching the spaces inside the third item.  Any advice what could be wrong with regex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert comma separated string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array)

Comment: Not a duplicate; this question also has empty item elimination and isn't just commas.

Comment: @Mike, is not the same.  I want to trim spaces, not using them as separators.

Comment: @Reuben,  I see.  I updated my answer to fit the bill for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Try this (edited)](https://jsfiddle.net/jaumzera/mvzde9ft/2/):

```js
var myStr = "item1, item2,,, this is item3; item4 , ";
var myArray = myStr.split(/\s*[,;]+\s*/).filter(Boolean);
alert(myArray);
```

Comment: Doesn't handle the trimming as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Well, I fixed the code the way you ask. I think it would attend you. Take a look, please.

Comment: @Jaumzera, its almost Ok, just the split let an empty item ("") at the end of array.

Comment: Well, I quit... I can't figure out a way to do that in a elegant and readable way.

Comment: Thanx @Ruben... it fits perfectly.

Comment: Thanks to @Jacob contribution, the `filter(Boolean)` avoid the empty item left at the end of array =)

Answer (score 1):

`[]` only contains single characters or character classes and only matches one character at a time. Therefore, `[(,\s);,]` really means any of these characters are matched: `(),;` or whitespace.

There are easier approaches than regex. Try this:

```
myArray = myStr
  .split(/[;,]/)                 
  .map(function (str) { 
    return str.replace(/(^\s+)|(\s+$)/g, ''); // Trim whitespace
  }) 
  .filter(Boolean);              // Filter away the empty strings
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return `["item1", "item2", "this", "is", "item3", "item4", ""]`?

Comment: @choz, The `.filter(Boolean)` removes any empty entries.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob.  Your code works great.  Anyway I  give the Ok  to the answer using regex.  I used your `filter(Boolean)` trick to delete the empty item in array which regex can't delete.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to ensure you always match at least one non-white-space character.  Try this:

```
myArray = myStr.split(/[\s]*[,;][,;\s]*/);
```

Comment: Almost done, just this regex let an empty item ("") at the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = myStr.split(/(?: , | ; | ,| ;|, |; |;|,)+/);  

 Then do a quick trim() and verify if the item has content other than whitespace
```

Would effectively split a string using , or ; as the separator

```js
var myStr = "item1, item2,,, this is item3; item4 , ";
var myArray = myStr.split(/(?: , | ; | ,| ;|, |; |;|,)+/); 
var newArray = [];
for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
 var checkArray = myArray[i].trim();
 if (checkArray.length > 0) { newArray.push(myArray[i]); }
}
myArray = newArray;

console.log(myArray);
```

---

***ANSWER 2***

The best answer I could come up with was one I made by combining @Jacob's answer and my answer above.

This will effectively  Accomplish the job in the fastest way possible

```js
var myStr = "item1, item2,,, this is item3; item4 , ";
var myArray = myStr.split(/(?:,|;)+/).map(function (str) {
  return str.replace(/(^\s+)|(\s+$)/g, '');
 }).filter(Boolean);
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Doesn't trim or eliminate empty entries as in the question.

Comment: Also, why replace a perfectly good character class with a less-efficient, less-readable alternation?

Comment: @Alan Well, mainly because of the requirements outlined in the OP where he wanted to match against more than one character sometimes

Comment: @Jacob sure it does.