# How do I change the array string into an array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

Suppose I have the data I write into the variable `str`

```
var str = "Volvo,Saab,Mercades,Audi";
// document.write(typeof str+"<br/><br/>"); => string
// document.write(str[0]+"<br/>"); => V
// document.write(str[1]+"<br/>"); => o

var obj = ["Volvo","Saab","Mercades","Audi"];
// document.write(typeof obj+"<br/><br/>"); => object
// document.write(obj[0]+"<br/>"); => Volvo
// document.write(obj[1]+"<br/>"); => Saab
```

How do I change the `str` variable into an array of types of objects, such as the variable `obj`?

Comment: use `str.split(',')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert comma separated string to array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array)

Comment: 0 research for the simple issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `str.split(',')`

```
var str = "Volvo,Saab,Mercades,Audi";
var arr = str.split(',');
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks @PrototypeChain turned out to be this easy :)

Comment: @DyanaPutry Accept the answer if your find it useful.