# How to split a JSON property value adding sub property names?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, split

I'm retrieving an array of JSON objects and then using [JS split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array) the contents of a property into a sub-array for parsing requirements.

But I'm not sure how to add a sub property name to that newly created array for that property.

So now when I do a split on the property using:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < recordsets[0].length; i++){ 
       recordsets[0][i].Chart_Name = recordsets[0][i].Chart_Name.split(',');                           
    }
```

I get the following output:

```
"Chart_Name":[  
            "Criticality",
            " Status"
         ],
```

But I'm aiming to add a property name to each array value like:

```
    "Chart_Name":[  
            {name: "Criticality"},
            {name: "Status"}
         ],
```

**Question:**

How can I split Json string into sub property array?

This is a gist of the JSON array for context:

```
[  
   [  
      {  
         "Dashboard_Name":"my dashboard",
         "Chart_Name":[  
            "Criticality",
            " Status"
         ]
      }  
   ]
]
```

Comment: Can you provide your JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return an object.

```
for (var i = 0; i < recordsets[0].length; i++){ 
    recordsets[0][i].Chart_Name = recordsets[0][i].Chart_Name.split(',').map(function (a) { 
        return { name: a };
    });
}
```

Or rewrite the whole a bit shorter

```
recordsets[0].forEach(function (a) { 
    a.Chart_Name = a.Chart_Name.split(',').map(function (b) { 
        return { name: b };
    });
});
```

Post edit suggestion without `split`

```
for (var i = 0; i < recordsets[0].length; i++){ 
    recordsets[0][i].Chart_Name = recordsets[0][i].Chart_Name.map(function (a) { 
        return { name: a };
    });
}
```

Or rewrite the whole a bit shorter

```
recordsets[0].forEach(function (a) { 
    a.Chart_Name = a.Chart_Name.map(function (b) { 
        return { name: b };
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm a bit curious: why do you use the split method instead of a straightforward `a.Chart_Name = a.Chart_Name.map(function(b) {return {"name": b};});`

Comment: @Eineki, i suppose `a.Chart_Name` is a string with comma sparators.

Comment: @NinaSchloz Ah, Ok. It appears to be an array, from the example. I noticed just now your answer was written earlier than the question edit with a sample of the structure.