# Covert comma-separated string to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to convert comma-separated string to array w/ quotes around each value in js:

```js
var ipd = 'field1,field2';
console.log('Img Pad string: ' + ipd); // field1,field2
var ipdarray = new Array();
ipdarray = ipd.split(',');
console.log('Img Pad array split: ' + typeof ipdarray); // object
console.log('Img Pad array: ' + ipdarray); // field1,field2
```

I want the array to be: ["field1","field2"]

Tried to follow this:  [Convert comma separated string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array)
but it's not converting to an array.

Comment: How about `console.log('Img Pad array: ', ipdarray)`?

Comment: Array is an Object....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is being converted to an array, but when you output the string (in console.log), the array is being coerced back into that string syntax because of the + operator (acting as a concatenator).**

Here is a more isolated example of what is happening:

```js
var string = 'field1,field2';
var arr = string.split(',');
console.log(Array.isArray(arr));
console.log(arr.length);

//When using the +, it will coerce into a string
console.log('Coerce to string ' + arr);

//When passing the array as an argument, it will stay an array
console.log('Stays and array', arr);
```

In order to preserve the array literal syntax, you'll need to [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the array before outputting it if you want to use the + operator, or you can just output the array as a separate argument to console.log

```
JSON.stringify(ipdarray);
```

See it in action:

```js
var ipd = 'field1,field2';
console.log('Img Pad string: ' + ipd); // field1,field2
var ipdarray = new Array();
ipdarray = ipd.split(',');
console.log('Img Pad array split: ' + typeof ipdarray); // object
console.log('Img Pad array: ' + JSON.stringify(ipdarray)); // ["field1","field2"]
// OR
console.log('Img Pad array: ', ipdarray); // ["field1","field2"]
```

Also, arrays are "object"s, but there are other ways to determine if that "object" is an instance of an array:

```js
var arr = [];
console.log(typeof arr);
console.log(arr instanceof Array)
console.log(Array.isArray(arr));
```

Comment: but this is not an array, is a string

Comment: @DanielPérez, what do you mean? I am using the code snippet provided by the OP. It was converted to an array, but when console logging with the + operator, it converts the array to a string

Comment: @KevBot - Thanks for the explanation, much appreciated

Comment: I mean that `JSON.stringify` return a string, despite that looks like an array of string, it is not, I thought that the OP wanted an array of string surrounded by `"`, like `['"field1"','"field2"']`

Answer (score 0):

Given input string you can use `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/[^,]+/g` to match one or more characters which are not comma `,`

```
var ipd = 'field1,field2';
var ipdarray = ipd.match(/[^,]+/g);
```

Note that  `+` operator converts array to string at

```
console.log('Img Pad array: ' + ipdarray); // field1,field2
```

use comma `,` operator at `console.log()` call

```
console.log('Img Pad array: ', ipdarray); // field1,field2
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = "field1,field2"

var b = a.split(',');

var c = b.map(function (v) {
return '"' + v + '"';
})

console.log(c);
console.log(c[0]);
console.log(c[1]);
```