# Converting a comma separated string into an array

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

```
'"alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"'
```

How can I convert the string into an array such that:

```
array = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"];
```

So I can call on individual elements of the array such that:

```
array[0] = "alpha"
```

I've attempted using str.split but am unsure of the correct usage to separate the quotation marks and commas.

Comment: Does this answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array

Comment: Where did you get that string? Is its format defined somewhere?

Comment: @CaleSweeney That's the thread I've been looking at but haven't been able to get it to work with the quotation marks, spaces and commas.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I edited the original post to clarify. This is the result using cors-anywhere to pull a variable from another website. The string of variables is truncated from the pulled data.

Comment: @SaeedLudeen: Which website? Is it actually JSON or something?

Comment: @Ryan Yes. It's not a homework assignment. I've got a website with an array stored correctly as array = ["alpha, "beta", "gamma"]

I've made a JSON request but this pulls the whole webpage as a single string. I then truncated this to just "alpha, "beta", "gamma" but it remains a string of text. I want to be able to convert this back into an array.

Comment: @SaeedLudeen: Don’t chop the brackets off. It’ll probably be valid JSON then. (No guarantees when you’re parsing JavaScript without a JavaScript parser, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the string so that it's valid [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON), then [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it:

```js
var str = '"alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"';
var json = '[' + str + ']';
var array = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(array[0])
```

Comment: Doesn't work when string is already inside another JSON object.

Comment: @EdgarQuintero not really sure what you're saying... "inside a JSON object"??

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick for you:

`str.replace(/\"/g, '').split(', ')`

Comment: This answer's behavior differs from the accepted answer. If one of the strings contain a comma, then the string is split into two entries with this approach, e.g. `"alpha, beta", "gamma"` becomes `["alpha, beta", "gamma"]` with the accepted answer, and `["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]` with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotations and spaces, then split on the comma

```
var str = '"alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"';
var strArray = str.replace(/"/g, '').replace(/ /g, '').split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly more efficient than the others; trim off the 1st and last `"` characters and split on the `", "` sequence.

```js
var str = '"alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"';
var str2 = str.substr(1, str.length - 2).split('", "');
console.log(str2);
```