# separating comma separated strings in to a new string

Tags: javascript, string

Is there a way to split a string which is comma separated in to a new string? Simular to `substring()` method and the `split()` method.

So I want to separated this by the commas in the string:

```
let str = "arg1,arg2,arg3"; //and so on
```

and then put each value into a new string like this:

```
let str1 = "arg1";
let str2 = "arg2";
let str3 = "arg3";
```

Is there a way to do that in JavaScript?

Comment: Why not just use an array instead of using individual variables?

Comment: Creating variables dynamically is not a good idea. Just use `.split` and work with the array it returns. [Convert comma separated string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2858121/218196)

Comment: Also related: [“Variable” variables in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5187530/218196)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do this concisely is to use destructuring on the `split` string:

```js
const str = "arg1,arg2,arg3";
const [str1, str2, str3] = str.split(',');
console.log(str1);
console.log(str2);
console.log(str3);
```

But it would usually be more appropriate to use an array instead

Comment: thanks for the help, and also very quickly how would you do this depend on the length of the string from a user input? if you get what I mean.

Comment: @HarrySmart If the number of items in the array isn't certain, I would definitely assign the result of the `split` to an actual array instead of destructuring into separate variable names.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I see. well thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string using `.split` and then use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) which will unpack the values from array

```js
let [str1, str2, str3] = "arg1,arg2,arg3".split(",");
console.log(str1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dynamic object if this `str` is dynamic,

```js
let str = "arg1,arg2,arg3";
let strArr = str.split(',');
let strObj = {};

strArr.forEach((item, index) => {
   strObj['str'+ index] = item;
});

for(let str in strObj) {
  console.log(`${str} : ${strObj[str]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const str = "arg1,arg2,arg3";

const [arg1,arg2,arg3] = str.split(',');

console.log(arg1,arg2,arg3);
```