# Get everything in string after a single comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have some problem with my string, the variable name is `accountcode`. I want only part of the string. I want everything in the string which is after the first `,`, excluding any extra space after the comma. For example:

`accountcode = "xxxx, tes";`

`accountcode = "xxxx, hello";`

Then I want to output like `tes` and `hello`.

I tried:

```js
var s = 'xxxx, hello';
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(','));
document.write(s);
```

Comment: So, just to clarify, `accountcode` is an string with multiple words separated by commas?

Comment: Do you just want the text after the *last* comma? Where `xxxx` could be anything?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yes I want get text after comma

Comment: @Mukyuu This is a javascript thread

Comment: @D.Smania ya that's right

Comment: @AbanaClara I know. But solution there is reusable.

Comment: Why is this marked as a duplicate? This is **not** Java.

Comment: I'm all for marking duplicates. But this one misses by a 6'2" ballerina split

Comment: Weird duplicate vote... Either pick [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/convert-comma-separated-string-to-array) as dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `split` with `trim`.

```js
var accountcode = "xxxx, tes";
var result= accountcode.split(',')[1].trim();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why include jquery?

Comment: This will error when there is no comma. And may not work as expected if there are many commas.

Comment: waaa thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`string.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) to pull the last word out without making a new array:

```js
let accountcode = "xxxx, hello";
let lastCommaIndex = accountcode.lastIndexOf(',')
let word = accountcode.slice(lastCommaIndex+1).trim()
console.log(word)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> The `split()` method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings, using a specified separator string to determine where to make each split.

You can use *length* property of the generated array as the last *index* to access the string item. Finally [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) the string:

```js
var s = 'xxxx, hello';
s = s.split(',');
s = s[s.length - 1].trim();
document.write(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the String on the comma.

```js
var s = 'xxxx, hello';
var parts = s.split(',');
console.log(parts[1]);
```

If you don't want any leading or trailing spaces, use [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

```js
var s = 'xxxx, hello';
var parts = s.split(',');
console.log(parts[1].trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
accountcode = "xxxx, hello";
let macthed=accountcode.match(/\w+$/)
    if(matched){
       document.write(matched[0])
    }
```

here `\w+` means any one or more charecter 
and `$` meand end of string 
so `\w+$` means get all the character upto end of the sting 
so here `' '` space is not a whole character so it started after space upto `$`

the `if` statement is required because if no match found than `macthed` will be null , and it found it will be an array and first element will be your match