# How Convert Value to Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm get data string lat and long google maps polygon.  I want to convert this value to array .

```
$value = "(-6.2811957386588855, 106.70141951079609),(-6.281142416506361, 106.70432702536823),(-6.2781776962328815, 106.70438066954853),(-6.2781776962328815, 106.70136586661579)";
```

I want the result like this Array :

```
$polygon = array(
        array(-6.2811957386588855, 106.70141951079609),
        array(-6.281142416506361, 106.70432702536823),
        array(-6.2781776962328815, 106.70438066954853),
        array(-6.2781776962328815, 106.70136586661579),
    );
```

Comment: What is `$value` here? is that a string or array?

Comment: where are you getting this data from initially in this format?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a comma separated string to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/how-to-convert-a-comma-separated-string-to-an-array)

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the string to valid JSON by converting parentheses to square brackets and adding a `[]` layer around the outside, and then `json_decode` it:

```
$value = '(-6.2811957386588855, 106.70141951079609),(-6.281142416506361, 106.70432702536823),(-6.2781776962328815, 106.70438066954853),(-6.2781776962328815, 106.70136586661579)';
$polygon = json_decode('[' . str_replace(array('(', ')'), array('[', ']'), $value) . ']', true);
print_r($polygon);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => -6.2811957386589
            [1] => 106.7014195108
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => -6.2811424165064
            [1] => 106.70432702537
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => -6.2781776962329
            [1] => 106.70438066955
        )    
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => -6.2781776962329
            [1] => 106.70136586662
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/aW8nU)

Comment: What happen if `), (` instead of `),(`?

Comment: @MH2K9 json_decode doesn't care about whitespace: https://3v4l.org/Ns79V

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode` with `trim` and `array_map`

```
$r = explode('),(',trim($value,'()'));
$c = array_map(function($v){return explode(',',$v);}, $r);
print_r($c);
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/fFAS0

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode()` function like this

```
$string = '(-6.2811957386588855, 106.70141951079609),(-6.281142416506361, 106.70432702536823),(-6.2781776962328815, 106.70438066954853),(-6.2781776962328815, 106.70136586661579)';
foreach(explode('),(',trim($string,'()')) as $single_array)
{
  $sub_array= array();
  foreach(explode(',',$single_array) as $sbs_array)
  {
      $sub_array[] = $sbs_array;
  }
  $result[] = $sub_array;
} 
print_r ($result);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => -6.2811957386588855
        [1] =>  106.70141951079609
    )

   [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => -6.281142416506361
        [1] =>  106.70432702536823
    )

   [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => -6.2781776962328815
        [1] =>  106.70438066954853
    )

   [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => -6.2781776962328815
        [1] =>  106.70136586661579
    )
```

)

Demo : https://3v4l.org/6HEAG

Answer (score 1):

Using [preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and [array_walk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) you can parse the coordinates as an array

```
$value = '(-6.2811957386588855, 106.70141951079609),(-6.281142416506361, 106.70432702536823),(-6.2781776962328815, 106.70438066954853),(-6.2781776962328815, 106.70136586661579)';
preg_match_all('/\(([0-9\-\s,.]+)\)/', $value, $matches);
array_walk($matches[1], function(&$val) { $val = explode(',', $val); });
$coordinates = $matches[1];
print_r($coordinates);
```

- Using `preg_match_all()` get all the coordinates as array of string
- Using `array_walk()` make an iteration over the coordinated array and [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) by the delimiter of comma (`,`)

---

- Working [demo](https://3v4l.org/ehSQr).
- [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YLjMbT/1).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using preg_match_all with array_map

```
$value = '(-6.2811957386588855, 106.70141951079609),(-6.281142416506361, 106.70432702536823),(-6.2781776962328815, 106.70438066954853),(-6.2781776962328815, 106.70136586661579)';


preg_match_all('#\(([\-\d\.]+),\s+([\-\d\.]+)\)#', $value, $matches);

$geo = array_map(function ($a, $b) {
   return [(float)$a, (float)$b];
}, $matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

**Output:**

```
array(4) {

[0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=> float(-6.2811957386589)
    [1]=> float(106.7014195108)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=> float(-6.2811424165064)
    [1]=> float(106.70432702537)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=> float(-6.2781776962329)
    [1]=> float(106.70438066955)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=> float(-6.2781776962329)
    [1]=> float(106.70136586662)
  }
}
```

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/zJP0T5/1)

Comment: Using regex for it is like using machine learning for a hello world. @Rakesh Jakhar answer is cleaner and fastest.

Comment: This analogy makes no sense. Regex is meant to extract data from strings, and this is a perfect example of using it. Invoking multiple functions doesn't make it clear at all. If the other developer saw that code, you would need to explain why you wrote like this. With REGEX it's straightforward.  I can only agree that his answer might be  faster. I haven't checked it though.