# How to seperate item in array using react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

user.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

const RecommendationDetail = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadRekko();
}, []);


  const loadRekko = async () => {
    const res = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/dashboard-rekko/${id}`,{
        headers:headers
    }); 


    console.log(res.data.response);
    var array = [];
    let a = (res.data.response.rekkoRecords.product_img)
    array.push(a)
    setImage(array)    ====>>> How can i make array like i want
    console.log(image)
    setRecommendation(res.data.response.rekkoRecords)
  }

 return (
    {image.map((it) => {
            return (
                <div key={it}>
                    <img src= {'http://localhost:3001/'+it} />
                </div>
            )
            
        })}
 )
}
```

Everything is working but I want to show multiple images. I am getting a response in `"uploads\classpamplate.png,uploads\classpamplate1.jpg"` this format and after pushing it in the array it becomes `["uploads\classpamplate.png,uploads\classpamplate1.jpg"]` but what I want is `["uploads\classpamplate.png","uploads\classpamplate1.jpg"]` both are separated so that I can show it using `.map()` function. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can get answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/how-can-i-convert-a-comma-separated-string-to-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming
a = "uploads\classpamplate.png,uploads\classpamplate1.jpg"

expected result = ["uploads\classpamplate.png","uploads\classpamplate1.jpg"]

Don't push `a` in the array, try below

```
setImage(a.split(','))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split them using `,` so that it'll be converted to an array

```
let a = (res.data.response.rekkoRecords.product_img).split(",");
array.push(...a)
```

or

Directly you can call `setImage` like below

```
setImage(res.data.response.rekkoRecords.product_img.split(","));
```

Check if the response is empty or not and then split

```
let a = (res.data.response.rekkoRecords.product_img);
a = a && a.split(",") || []
setImage([...a])
```

Comment: How can I put check if there will be no image it will not show anything as if I have one image then it has a length as 1 and if there is no image then also it has a length 1

Comment: I have updated the answer to check if the received response is empty or not and then splitting. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to separate that string by comma `,`:

> The `split()` method divides a String into an ordered list of substrings, puts these substrings into an array, and returns the array.

```
let a = (res.data.response.rekkoRecords.product_img)
setImage(a.split(','))
```

See a live example below:

```js
const data = `uploads\classpamplate.png,uploads\classpamplate1.jpg`
const result = data.split(',')
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just split the string by `,`. it will return a new array

```
let result = (res.data.response.rekkoRecords.product_img).split(',');
let array = [...result];
```