# how to split array into miltiple array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have an array output

```
["AA janral store shahid bhai Islam pura,31.592887,74.4292156,1~", "Almakkah store shahid bhai gunj bazar,31.5645088,74.3838828,1~", "hamad hassan Nafees backery,31.595234,74.3565654,1~"]
```

**but required output is in javascript**

[Array(), Array(), Array()]

example

```
var ar = [
      ['AA janral store shahid bhai Islam pura',31.592887,74.4292156,1],//(array)
      ['Almakkah store shahid bhai gunj bazar',31.5645088,74.3838828,1],//(array)
      ['hamad hassan Nafees backery',31.595234,74.3565654,1]//(array)
     ];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a comma-separated string to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/how-can-i-convert-a-comma-separated-string-to-an-array)

Comment: no this is different one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If commas are always separators, so:

```js
const arr = ["AA janral store shahid bhai Islam pura,31.592887,74.4292156,1~", "Almakkah store shahid bhai gunj bazar,31.5645088,74.3838828,1~", "hamad hassan Nafees backery,31.595234,74.3565654,1~"];
const res = [...arr.map(item => item.split(","))];
console.log(res);
```

The same with filtering blank strings:

```js
const arr = ["AA janral store shahid bhai Islam pura,31.592887,74.4292156,1~", "", "Almakkah store shahid bhai gunj bazar,31.5645088,74.3838828,1~", "hamad hassan Nafees backery,31.595234,74.3565654,1~"];
const res = [...arr.reduce((items, item) => (item.length && (items = [...items, item.split(",")]), items), [])];
console.log(res);
```

With different variants of incoming data:

```js
const arr = ["AA janral store shahid bhai Islam pura,31.592887,74.4292156, ", "", " ", ",,,,,", "Almakkah store shahid bhai gunj bazar,31.5645088,74.3838828,1~", "hamad hassan Nafees backery,31.595234,74.3565654,1~"];
const res = [...arr.reduce((items, item) => {
        const splitted = item.split(",").filter(item => item.trim().length);
        if (splitted.length) items.push(splitted);
        return items;
    }, [])];
console.log(res);
```

Comment: you r genious:) thanx helped

Comment: but help me in one thing in the last it passes  " "(that) i dont want (" ") example ["AA janral store shahid bhai Islam pura,31.592887,74.4292156,1", " "]

Comment: I added an example with an empty string.

Comment: I also added the most complex example that I could think of.

Comment: legend bro but i want some more complexity like ["AA janral store shahid bhai Islam pura", 31.592887, 74.4292156, 1] means [ "string" , 1234,456 , 1] i am spliting value using '~' but in return it pass me string ["Almakkah store shahid bhai gunj bazar", "31.5645088,74.3838828,1", ""]  but required is [ "string in cotation" , number without double cotation , 1]