# want to convert the values of data in an object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

i have an object like this

```
{make: 'Audi,BMW,Cadillac', model: 'RDX,Mop,Rvn'}
```

What to convert it to this

```
{make: ['Audi','BMW','Cadillac'], model: ['RDX','Mop','Rvn']}
```

Comment: Are you definitely after arrays with _one_ element in them and not multiple (eg: `['Audi', 'BMW', 'Cadillac']` instead of `['Audi,BMW,Cadillac']`)? What have you tried so far to achieve this / what are you struggling with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a comma-separated string to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/how-can-i-convert-a-comma-separated-string-to-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries` functions handles this case well.

```js
const data = {make: 'Audi,BMW,Cadillac', model: 'RDX,Mop,Rvn'};

const dataWithArrays = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(data)
        .map(([key, value]) => [key, value.split(',')])
);

console.log(dataWithArrays);
```

Comment: its showing like this ['Audi,BMW,Cadillac'] 
what i want is ['Audi','BMW','Cadillac']

Comment: Originally the question was framed differently. I have updated the answer to reflect the changes to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

`obj.make = obj.make.split(",")`

`obj.model = obj.model.split(",")`

Answer (score 0):

Simple any easy, using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
const data = {make: 'Audi,BMW,Cadillac', model: 'RDX,Mop,Rvn'};

const res = Object.keys(data)
   .reduce((acc, k) => (acc[k] = data[k].split(','), acc), {})

console.log(res);
```