# Replacing strings with arrays in JSON to be used in Vue app

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs3

I've spent too long trying to figure this out on my own and I wouldn't be surprised if this is very simple.

Basically, I'm receiving JSON from an api. This data will then be used in a Vue component to dynamically populate html with content.

The problem that I'm having is that some information in the JSON must be in the form of an array so that I can iterate over it with a Vue "v-if", however I receive this information from the api as a string.

I now receive: "subjects": "English,Biology".
However I need this to be: "subjects": ["English","Biology"]

Here's my current code:

JSON example:

```
{
  "employees": [
  {
    "id": 7099,
    "first_name": "Angela",
    "subjects": "English,Biology",
  },
  {
    "id": 7100,
    "first_name": "Aeliana",
    "subjects": "English,French",
  } 
]
}
```

Vue component essentials:

```
<template>
    <div v-for="employee in employees" :key="employee.id">
      <p>
        {{ employee.first_name }}
      </p>
      <p>
        {{ employee.subjects }}
      </p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      employees: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/employees')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.employees = data)
      .catch(err => console.log(err.message)) 
  }
}
</script>
```

At the moment, my code works with v-if and the names and subjects appear in the html. The problem is that the 'subjects' appear together as a string. I need this to be in an array so that I can use another v-if to place each subject in a separate element.

After thinking about the problem and reading around, I made this simple code which accomplishes something similar:

```
const employees = [{'name':'john','subjects':'maths,science'},{'name':"mark",'subjects':'english,maths'}];

for (employee of employees) {
    employee.subjects = employee.subjects.split(',')
    console.log(employee.subjects);
}
```

However, I cannot adapt this above code to my original project.

I've tried so many things without success. I'm sure there's an extremely simple solution that I just can't find. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This works wonderfully. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a comma-separated string to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858121/how-can-i-convert-a-comma-separated-string-to-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Add a method and use it in a v-for

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="subject in splitSubjects(employee.subjects)" :key="subject">
    {{ subject }} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

using

```
...
methods: { 
  splitSubjects: subjectsStr => subjectsStr.split(',')
}
```